# Goal seek multiple rows - MS-Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

i have 5028 rows excluding the headings and 3 columns, want to set value 1.7 in the cloumn "C" by changing the value in the column "B".

using goal seek option it is possible only for one cell. i want to do the same for 5028 rows, please help to do the task by running some macro.

Comment: It should be possible.  Have you tried experimenting with making your own macros?  Excel can create a macro automatically by recording your actions and later you can edit the code it made.

Comment: Curious... is this some sort of one-way hash that would prevent you from just reversing the calculation to determine the value in Column B?  I.e., a simple formula?  Sounds like you might not need a macro or the "Goal Seek" feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Bustos pointed to the right idea, here is a working solution:

```
Public Sub Demo()
  Dim rngRow As Range
  For Each rngRow In UsedRange.Rows
    rngRow.Cells(1, 3).GoalSeek Goal:=1.7, ChangingCell:=rngRow.Cells(1, 2)
  Next rngRow
End Sub
```

*Edit:*

Use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows` instead of `UsedRange.Rows`, if you intend to use this as a Macro in a Modul, not as one of a Worksheet - or any other reference to a valid Range.

For your example, you might prefer to use: `Range("A2:C5028").Rows`  or `MySheet.Range("A2:C5028").Rows`.

*Edit:*

```
Public Sub Demo()
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim rngRow As Range
  For Each rngRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows 
    rngRow.Cells(1, 3).GoalSeek Goal:=1.7, ChangingCell:=rngRow.Cells(1, 2)
  Next rngRow
End Sub
```

Comment: hi jook, thanks a lot.. but i am zero in vba, i just tried to copy your code in module and execute, i got 'object required' error, then as u said i changed it to activesheet.usedrange.rows, then i get 'reference is not valid' error. please help, if possible please give me exact code which can be palaced into the module.

Comment: @davidb ok, now, this won't break, but remember, it takes quite a while for 5028 rows. It should work as a Module-Macro. If you need it to only be used on one specific worksheet or area, use e.g. `CodeNameOfYourWorksheet.Range("A2:C5028").Rows` - the codename is not the same as the worksheet-name you can see in excel - just google it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a macro which loops and then does a Range-Goal seek - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb209907%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is good code. I modified it for my purpose, which is for not just a column but multiple columns. In order to run my code, you must first select (highlight) all the cells you wish to GoalSeek (connected like in a table, not separate areas). My code:

```
Sub GoalSeek_To_0()
' Macro created 15 Jun '18 by Benjamin Cohen

On Error Resume Next

Dim row_, col_ As Range
Dim i_, j_ As Integer
' i_ = 1
  j_ = 1

For Each col_ In Selection.Columns
 For Each row_ In Selection.Rows
  row_.Cells(1, j_).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=row_.Cells(1, j_).Offset(0, -1)
   row_.Cells(1, j_).Value = 1
 Next row_
  j_ = j_ + 1
Next col_

End Sub
```